# Hiding directory names in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to change 
http://localhost/project/views/login.php 
for something like: 
http://localhost/project/login

Only editing the .htaccess file.

The problem is that I never did something like that and I wish to understand how to use this file for good.

I will really appreciate any comment about hiding extension files and directories.

Comment: this site is not for providing extensive tutorials, but for answering specific questions. i think you are very right with the idea to want to learn it for good, but for that you should use a search engine and find tutorials and follow them.

Comment: Hoojui is right, you may want to start with this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/

Comment: Changing the URL structure is not something you do by "Only editing the .htaccess file.". Step#1 of changing the URL structure (or "hiding the directory name") is to change the URLs in your application. Otherwise, _every_ request is going to result in a redirection.